# Why do I get QuerySet object has no attribute user

Tags: python, django

I am working on a website using Django, where users can send friend 
request to another user and I came up with an error on my code. Queryset object has no attribute user. According to my attached images, when I click on the follow button of the first user, all buttons changes text to 'cancel', but when I click on the button of the second user it does not change the text. I want when button clicked button text should be able to change for each users.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
def home(request):
    p = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
    u = p.user
    sent_request = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user)
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all()
        button_status = 'not_friend'
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_uset=request.user).filter(to_user=p.user)) == 1:
            button_status='add_request'
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
            button_status='cancel_request'

context = {'u':u, 'p':p, 'sent_request',:sent_request, 'button_status':button_status,} 

return render(request, 'home.html', context) 


{% for profile in p %} 
{{ profile }} 
{% if not request.user in u %} 
{% if button_status == 'not_friend' %} 
href = add url here 
{% elif button_staus == 'cancel_request' %} 
href = cancel request url here
{%  endif %} 
{% endif %}
{% endfor %} 


#This only execute once on template, instead of twice (duplicate). How do I make this display twice in template? 
{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
{%  data.0.user.username %}
#All codes here
{% endfor %}

{% if forloop.counter == 1 %} 
{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
#All codes here
{%  data.0.user.username %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Try `p.first().user`

Comment: @Clarity.. When I use p.first().user it gives me only the first user on the list, but I want all user exclude the current user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.exclude()` will give you an queryset. So, you have to first iterate that `queryset` and get required user from there.

Because `queryset` it mean the `list`.

I think you have to pass `zip` of profiles list `p` and button status list `button_status` of a particular users as below...

```
def home(request):
    p = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
    all_profile_users = []
    button_status_list = []                

    for user_obj in p:

        u = user_obj.user
        all_profile_users.append(u)
        sent_request = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=u)

        friends = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user, friends__id=user_obj.id).exist()


        button_status = 'none'
        if not friends
            button_status = 'not_friend'
            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_uset=request.user).filter(to_user=p.user)) == 1:
                button_status='add_request'
            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
                button_status='accept_request'

        button_status_list.append(button_status)

    context = {'u':all_profile_users, 'profile_and_button_status': zip(p, button_status_list), 'sent_request':sent_request}
```

Then, iterate `profile_and_button_status` in template as below...

```
{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}

    <div class="row mb-2">
        ... YOUR DESIGN CODE ...
        {{ data.0.user.username }}

   {% if not request.user in u %} 

       {% if data.1 == 'not_friend' %}
            ... YOUR DESIGN CODE ...

       {% elif data.1 == 'follow_request_sent' %}  
            ... YOUR DESIGN CODE ...
```

And so on for other conditions.

**For remove friend :**

```
def remove_friend(request, id):
    ... YOUR LOGIC ...
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=from_user, to_user=request.user).first()
    if frequest is None:
        frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=from_user).first()
    user1 = frequest.to_user
    user2 = from_user
    ... YOUR LOGIC ...
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209422/discussion-on-answer-by-mk-patel-why-do-i-get-queryset-object-has-no-attribute-u).